Gparted window is frozen
I have a laptop with two partitions Windows and Ubuntu 17.0. I decreased the size of the windows partition, using the windows utility, to create some free space. Now I was using gparted to move the ubuntu partition to the left and expand it over the new free space. I ran gparted and started this task correctly, but after a couple of minutes the window got frozen. I never saw a progress bar, just a message at the bottom with the pending operation. It is an old laptop, so I expect everything to be slow, but 2 hours have passed and I don't know if it is really doing anything. I suspect it is not. The status is S and it does not look to me that it is working at all. I just want to know how to check if gparted is really doing something. Should I kill the gparted process? That will probably create problems. What can I do?

Ubuntu 17.10 or the 2017-October release is EOL (end-of-life). https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/07/19/ubuntu-17-10-artful-aardvark-end-of-life-reached-on-july-19-2018/   Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades but note it's no longer supported on this site due to EOL status (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

There is no Ubuntu 17.0 release, as Ubuntu uses a year.month format and 0 isn't a valid month; but all releases from 2017 are EOL, with the 2017-October release (17.10) the latest release of that year

@TalaatEtman Thank you. I waited and gparted finally crashed and the program closed (?). I rebooted it with no problem, so I repeated the process again and this time worked perfectly (it was actually quite fast)
